Linker error when binding too many functions to Lua with Sol2 (C++)
I'm writing several bindings with sol2. Currently I have this
https://pastebin.pl/view/2bd658d4
This works normally on Linux. But last night i tried to put in on Windows to test out. And i'm getting a fking wall of error at the final step (Linking exe) https://paste.ofcode.org/GRQqhX8NHrCWShi43z4AaU (only one portion, it is 5 times as long as this)
I tried several part of the code, tried to used each bind function individually and every single one works, a few together also works. Only when I tried to put them all in did it crash like above
#include <beaver/core.hpp>
#include <beaver/scripting.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    beaver::sdlgame sdl {"test", 1280, 720};
    sol::state lua;
    beaver::ecs_core<> ecs; // contains several components
    beaver::init_lua(lua);
    beaver::bind_core(sdl, lua);
    auto tbl = lua["pp"].get_or_create<sol::table>();
    // beaver::bind_ecs_core_components(sss,game,f,lua); // this functions call every bind functions below
    bind_entity(ecs, tbl);
    bind_position(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_velocity(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_scale(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_rotation(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_pivot(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_color(ecs,tbl,lua);
    bind_oscillation(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_flipflag(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_tile_animation(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_cbox(ecs,tbl,lua);
    bind_state(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_image_render(ecs, tbl, lua);
    // bind_entity_render(ecs, sdl, tbl, lua); // Sample comment. This is enough to crash. I have to comment 2 more
    // bind_timer(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_stopwatch(ecs, tbl, lua);
    bind_particle(ecs, tbl, lua);

    lua.script_file("testt.lua");
    beaver::run_game(sdl, [&](float dt){return true;},
        [&]()
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl._graphics._rdr, 255,255,255,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(sdl._graphics._rdr);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl._graphics._rdr, 0,0,0,255);
            sdl._graphics.line(10,10,500,500);
        });

}

I don't know what the error is and how to deal with it.
I use CMake, MinGW to build. I passed gcc and g++ to the cmake command.

A [mre] should be posted. The first errors and the prior command invocation should be posted in a code block

"I don't know what the error is and how to deal with it" -- you don't know what an undefined symbol linker error is? It's not some unscrutable error, it's the most basic error there is: you just aren't linking the necessary libraries or object files. And if you think you do (considering you seem to be also coding in Linux), you're linking the wrong ones.

If I comment 3 more lines of bind, it compiles normally. So I don't know what's wrong here

What was the exact build command that produced these linker errors?
